# Angular 4 - Could not resolve submodule for routing

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I'm building a webapp with Angular 4. I have a top-level routing module and a separate routing module for each submodule (e.g. HomeModule).

This is my top-level routing configuration:

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {path: '', loadChildren: './home#HomeModule'},
  {path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent},
];
```

When I run `ng server`, I get a strange error, that module `home` was not found. The app does not work in the browser.

The strange part is the following: When a file is changed and webpack recompiles the project, everything works just fine and the routing works.
The error does only appear when I'm running `ng serve`.

This is the error I get when I'm running `ng serve`, not when the project is recompiled because of a file change:

```
ERROR in Error: Could not resolve module ./home relative to /path/to/my/project/src/app/app.module.ts
    at StaticSymbolResolver.getSymbolByModule (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:31884:30)
    at StaticReflector.resolveExternalReference (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:30350:62)
    at parseLazyRoute (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:28616:55)
    at listLazyRoutes (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:28578:36)
    at visitLazyRoute (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:29995:47)
    at AotCompiler.listLazyRoutes (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:29963:20)
    at AngularCompilerProgram.listLazyRoutes (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/transformers/program.js:157:30)
    at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.listLazyRoutes (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_api.js:44:36)
    at AngularCompilerPlugin._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:247:66)
    at Promise.resolve.then.then (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:538:50)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Lazy Loading route configuration](https://angular.io/guide/router#lazy-loading-route-configuration): *The address is the AdminModule file location (**relative to the app root**), followed by a # separator, followed by the name of the exported module class, AdminModule.*

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I was using the absolute path convention: `app/home#HomeModule` and it **wasn't** working.

I then tried the **relative** path convention: `./home#HomeModule` and it worked.

> ... in the CLI, the paths to lazy routes should be relative from the file you're in

[Source](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6246#issuecomment-300462984)

---

I followed this [Tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/lazy-loading-in-angular-v2) and it used the absolute path convention and it worked.

Would love to know why the inconsistency...

---

**UPDATE:**

As [Friedrich mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43633062/error-building-angular-cli/50606826#50606826), to make it work using an Absolute Path, update `src/tsconfig.app.json` as follows:

```
{
  ...,
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...,
    baseUrl: "./"
  }
}
```

Comment: I append  ./  to my module name and it works for me thanks

Comment: @spottedmahn: The path `app/home#HomeModule` **is** working, but you have to add `baseUrl: "./"` in the `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.app.json` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50606826/5816097).

Comment: Thanks, my problem was needing to omit the `*.ts` extension

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue and none of the answers above worked for me,the final solution i found was using the absolute path of the module and module class name after the '#'.

```
    export const ROUTES: Routes = [
       {path: '', loadChildren: 'src/app/pathToYourModule/home.module#HomeModule'},
       {path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent}
     ];
```

I started the path from 'src' and dont forget to remove the '.ts' from the module path.

Comment: Thank you for the last statement! Apparently, had forgot to remove .ts from the path!

Answer (score 10):

You have to remove the .ts suffix from the reference to your module file:
 {path: '', loadChildren: 'app/pathToYourModule/home.module#HomeModule'},

Answer (score 4):

I have faced a similar issue and resolved by **removing the extension** from the module name and adding a **relative path**.

Code which was throwing an error:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'settings',
        loadChildren: 'app/setting/setting.module.ts#SettingsModule'
    }
];
```

Working code:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'settings',
        loadChildren: './setting/setting.module#SettingsModule'
    }
];
```

Hope it helps!

**Note:** On Angular version - 7.0.0

Answer (score 3):

For those who are not able to find a solution, simply remove ".ts" extension from the loadChildren line.

```
 {path: '', loadChildren: './home.ts#HomeModule'},
```

to

```
{path: '', loadChildren: './home#HomeModule'},
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the absolute path of your module with the module file name like so:

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {path: '', loadChildren: 'app/pathToYourModule/home.module.ts#HomeModule'},
  {path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent},
];
```

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

As of Angular 8+ there is new syntax for lazyloading modules this is the issue I ran into looking at older code examples.

Previousely:

```
 const routes: Routes = [
   { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule' }
 ];
```

As of Angular 8+:

```
  const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: 'dashboard', 
      loadChildren: () =>
        import('./dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule)
    }
  ];
```

[Michael Hoffmann explains here](https://dev.to/mokkapps/manually-lazy-load-modules-and-components-in-angular-1189)

> Since Angular 8 we can use the browser’s built-in dynamic imports to load JavaScript modules asynchronous in Angular. A lazy-loaded module can be defined in the routing configuration using the new import(...) syntax for loadChildren:

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue, for me I simply forgot to add `.module` to the file name.

I had this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  /* ... */
  {
    path: 'page-not-found',
    loadChildren: './modules/page-not-found/page-not-found#PageNotFoundModule' // <- page-not-found missing .module
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'page-not-found'
  }
];
```

Should be:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  /* ... */
  {
    path: 'page-not-found',
    loadChildren: './modules/page-not-found/page-not-found.module#PageNotFoundModule'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'page-not-found'
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which took days to resolve but I ended up going back to recheck the structure of each statement/path. Below is what I had before:

```
      {
    path: 'payments',
    loadChildren: './pages/service-payments/service-payments.module#ServicePaymentsPageModule'
  }
```

I then changed the path as below:

```
      {
    path: 'payments',
    loadChildren: '../service-payments/service-payments.module#ServicePaymentsPageModule'
  }
```

I hope it helps somebody in the future.